# running sphinx in two different apps on the same server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am having two small apps having search in it. They are completly two different apps with different database etc.

Now the issue is coming up pid file.At a time only on application is searching cause when I do

```
rake ts:start
```

on one it says another instance is already running.
How can I change this so that sphinx keep running for both the applications. I am using Capistrano for development.

Structure is something like this:

```
  /home/me/my_app_1/production/current
  /home/me/my_app_2/production/current
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both apps you have to create a `config/sphinx.yml` which can contain various configuration variables and one of them allows you to specify the port of the sphinx server. When you define the port manually in one app like this:

```
development:
  port: 9313
test:
  port: 9314
production:
  port: 9316
```

and in the other:

```
development:
  port: 9317
test:
  port: 9318
production:
  port: 9319
```

Then call `rake ts:rebuild` in both applications. Thinking sphinx will generate new config files for sphinx that setup different sphinx instances for each app and each environment in the app.